# TypeError raised when running my code

Tags: actionscript-3

I get the following error when I try run my code.

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

```
    private function calculateFIX001Value(custfields:Array):Number
    {
        var result:Number = new Number;
        var valueObj:Object;

        try{
                var markUp:Number = 0.01;
                var projectValue:String = "";
                var marketCategory:String = "";

                for each (var custField:Object in custfields)
                {
                    if (custField.fieldLabel == 'Segment Category')
                        marketCategory = custField.selectedValue[0];

                    if (custField.fieldLabel == 'Project Value (R)')
                        projectValue = custField.selectedValue[0].toString().replace("R","");
                        projectValue = projectValue.replace(",","");
                        projectValue = projectValue.replace(",","");
                        projectValue = projectValue.replace(",","");
                }

                switch (marketCategory)
                {
                    case "23": //5% Markup for Building
                        markUp = new Number(5 / 100);
                        break;
                    case "24": //11% Markup for Civils
                        markUp = new Number(11 / 100);
                        break;
                    case "25": //2% Markup for Scaffolding
                        markUp = new Number(2 / 100);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if ((projectValue != "" && projectValue != '0') && marketCategory != "")
                {
                    var revenue:Number = new Number;
                    //if (!_model.myProfile.switchOpportunityInMillions)
                    //  revenue = parseFloat(projectValue) * 1000000 * markUp;
                    //else
                        revenue = parseFloat(projectValue) * markUp;
                    valueObj = new Object;
                    valueObj.label = "Expected Revenue";
                    valueObj.value = revenue;
                    //result.push(valueObj);
                    result = revenue;
                    //rm.saveOpportunityValue(_currentOpportunity.id, revenue);
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorObj:Object = new Object;
                    var errMsg:String = "";

                    if (projectValue == '' || projectValue == '0')
                        errMsg = "Project value not specified";

                    if (marketCategory == "")
                    {
                        if (errMsg != "")
                            errMsg += " or no Segment Category has been selected";
                        else
                            errMsg = "No Segment Category has been selected";
                    }
                    errorObj.label = 'Cannot calculate value.';
                    errorObj.value = errMsg + '.';
                    //result.push(errorObj);

                    result = 0;
                }
        } catch(e:Error) {
            Alert.show(e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeError: Error #1010 is also known as "Null Pointer Exception", meaning you trying to access a null object property.

If you look at the line the stack trace tells you, you might found the reason without much problem.

Comment: Hi there,  I am still a beginner at Action Script, how do I find the stack trace?

Comment: Most likely `selectedValue` property of your objects is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an indirect answer to help you solve your problem:  (as there are lots of things in your code that could potentially be null or undefined and cause this error)

You have almost all your code in a `try/catch`, so your error isn't actually getting thrown, you're just tracing out the error that was caught.

Throw the error (either by removing the try/catch or throwing it manually in the catch block):

```
catch(e:Error) {
    Alert.show(e.toString()); //instead of this, for debugging, do the line below:
    Throw e; //this will throw the error, so you will get your stack trace and the line number of error
}
```

To get the line number of the error and see the stack trace, you need to be running in the debug player or your IDE (eg Flash or FlashBuilder).